# Javascript innerHtml quiz results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to return the output of the score from a three button radio button quiz. I have the ouput working when I use alert but as the quiz is contained within a modal I don't want a popup I just want to display the output as within the modal to make it look cleaner I'm using InnerHTML however when I click the button I now get no output. I've been experimenting with using JQuery to try and show the results and hide the button but this isn't helping either. Does anyone know how I can  get the results to print to "results"?

Thanks

```js
<script>
          
var answers = ["A","B","B"], 
    tot = answers.length;

function getCheckedValue( radioName ){
    var radios = document.getElementsByName( radioName ); // Get radio group by-name
    for(var y=0; y<radios.length; y++)
      if(radios[y].checked) return radios[y].value; // return the checked value
}

function getScore(){
  var score = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<tot; i++)
    if(getCheckedValue("question"+i)===answers[i]) score += 1; // increment only
  return score;
}

function returnScore(){
  print("Your score is "+ getScore() +"/"+ tot);
}
</script>

var answers = ["A","B","B"], 
    tot = answers.length;

function getCheckedValue( radioName ){
    var radios = document.getElementsByName( radioName ); // Get radio group by-name
    for(var y=0; y<radios.length; y++)
      if(radios[y].checked) return radios[y].value; // return the checked value
}

function getScore(){
  var score = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<tot; i++)
    if(getCheckedValue("question"+i)===answers[i]) score += 1; // increment only
  return score;
}

function returnScore(){
  document.getElementById("results").innerHtml ("Well done! You scored "+ getScore() +"/"+ tot);
  
}
</script>
```

```html
                <p> You are only charged interest on the amount that is remaining at the end of the month<br>
                <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A"> True </radio> 
                <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B"> False </radio> <br><hr>
               </p>
               
               <p>I have to pay off the balance in full every month <br><p>
                <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A"> True </radio> 
                <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B"> False </radio> <br> <hr>
               
               
               <p>If I don't make a payment my credit score will be unaffected <br></p>
                <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A"> True </radio> 
                <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B"> False </radio>
    

                <br><br>
                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll" onclick = "returnScore()">Results</button>

<h4 id="results"> </h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with `document.getElementById("results").innerHtml ("Well done! You scored "+ getScore() +"/"+ tot);` innerHTML is not a function, you have to assign value to in.

It should be `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Well done! You scored "+ getScore() +"/"+ tot;`

Comment: Isn't bringing up anything still it has stopped trying to print the page though.

Comment: Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/m563ev87/ , make sure there are no typos, its `innerHTML` not `innerHtml` , notice the capital HTML